# Automatically create child feature when creating parent

Tags: qgis, feature-layer

Is it possible to create a system where there is a geospatial layer linked to a number of non-spatial child tables so that when creating a feature in the parent layer child features are also created in the correct child table with no additional user input?

Basically I want a spatial layer with the following fields:

| fid | ObservationID | TypeOfObservation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Masonry |
| 2 | 2 | Timber |
| 3 | 3 | Masonry |

There will be five different Types of Observation, each with different attributes so these will be in five separate non-spatial tables. Each of these five tables should have the ObservationID added automatically when the spatial feature in the parent layer is created but the other attribute values will be filled out separately (in a form). So from the above parent layer the following child features would be created:

TableObservationTypeMasonry:

| fid | ObservationID | Material | BondMaterial | More attribute fields specific to masonry buildings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |  |  |

TableObservationTypeTimber

| fid | ObservationID | TimberType | Condition | More attribute fields specific to timber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |

Is there a way to set this up so that the child features will be created in the correct table? Can I do this so that when a parent feature is created the child feature is also created with no additional user input?

Comment: To clarify, will the attribute fields themselves will be different per observation, or will they share attribute fields and have different attribute values?

Perhaps you could make a couple of dummy tables to show what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Matt I've updated the question to try to clarify what I'm intending and with more clearly drawn example tables